# ADODB Command Parameters Refresh doesn't retrieve parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, iis, vbscript, adodb

I have an old web application, built with VBScript on an IIS6 Server with a SQL Server 2008 database. It is in the processed of being moved to a new server, on IIS8.

Every queries in the app work with stored procedures, with which we never had a problem. But on the new server, it doesn't seem to work. I found it it's because the `Command.Parameters.Refresh` doesn't return the parameters properly.

Consider this code:

```vb
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = 4
cmd.CommandText = v_strSpName
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
cmd.Parameters.Refresh

For i = LBound(v_arrParameters) To UBound(v_arrParameters)
    If m_bReplaceEmptyToNull Then
        v_arrParameters(i)(1) = ReplaceEmpty(v_arrParameters(i)(1))
    End If

    cmd.Parameters(v_arrParameters(i)(0)).value = v_arrParameters(i)(1)
Next
```

Everything in `v_arrParameters` exists, but I tried iterating in Parameters.name after the refresh, the parameters are not returned (but they are on the production server).

Also worth noting, the SQL Profiler does receive the query and return the parameters:

```
exec [Database]..sp_procedure_params_rowset N'get_company',1,N'dbo',NULL
```

According to [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/174223), it is a known issue, I just want to make sure it doesn't come from this problem, and find a solution or an alternative that doesn't imply a full rewriting of the application.

Also, no I can not update the SQL Server version, switch to VB.NET, there is always the issue that there is a client that won't pay for this problem.

Comment: Sorry I missed where that page states it's a known issue? The closest I can see to what you describe as a *"Known Issue"* is *"Parameters.refresh **will fail in some situations** or return information that is not entirely correct."*. What situations, it doesn't say. Personally, I don't use `.Refresh()` for this very reason as I had issues with support in Providers before using this method.

Comment: @Lankymart That's what I was talking about with this "known issue", but not saying the situations is pretty unhelpful. What do you use instead of `.Refresh()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we managed to make it work this way:

- Opening the Applications Pools section in IIS Manager.
- Going in the Advanced Settings of the Default App Pool (its name here, maybe not for everyone, I don't know)
- Setting `Enable 32-bits apps` to `True`

This is on a 64-bit Windows Server 2012 R2, with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6241.0 (X64) .